# Keypad listener wont compile

Tags: java, keylistener

So I’m not able to get this code to compile. I am using an outdated book to learn with and most everything has been working so far. I’ve only ran into a couple of snags that were easy to solve by googling but this one is a little more complicated I guess. Below is the two sections of code that throw errors.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CalculatorKeypad extends JPanel {

private JButton[] buttons;
private Vector listeners;

public CalculatorKeypad() {
    super();
    GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.weightx = gbc.weighty = 1.0;
    gbc.ipadx = gbc.ipady = 5;

    //bLabels is an array of button labels in order
    String[] bLabels = {
        CalculatorKeypadEvent.MR, 
        CalculatorKeypadEvent.MC,
        CalculatorKeypadEvent.MADD,
        CalculatorKeypadEvent.MSUBTRACT,
        CalculatorKeypadEvent.MS,
        CalculatorKeypadEvent.SQRT,
        CalculatorKeypadEvent.C,
        CalculatorKeypadEvent.AC,
        CalculatorKeypadEvent.POW,
        CalculatorKeypadEvent.DIVIDE,
        CalculatorKeypadEvent.MULTIPLY,
        CalculatorKeypadEvent.SUBTRACT,
        CalculatorKeypadEvent.CK7,
        CalculatorKeypadEvent.CK8,
        CalculatorKeypadEvent.CK9,
        CalculatorKeypadEvent.SIGN,
        CalculatorKeypadEvent.CK4,
        CalculatorKeypadEvent.CK5,
        CalculatorKeypadEvent.CK6,
        CalculatorKeypadEvent.ADD,
        CalculatorKeypadEvent.CK1,
        CalculatorKeypadEvent.CK2,
        CalculatorKeypadEvent.CK3,
        CalculatorKeypadEvent.EQUALS,
        CalculatorKeypadEvent.CK0,
        CalculatorKeypadEvent.DECIMAL,
    };

    //there are four columns of buttons
    int cols = 4;

    //build the button array and add to panel
    buttons = new JButton[bLabels.length];
    setLayout(gbl);

    ActionEventHandler actionListener = new ActionEventHandler();
    KeyEventListener keyListener = new KeyEventListener();
    
    for (int b = 0; b < buttons.length; b++) {
        buttons[b] = new JButton(bLabels[b]);
        
        //set different constraints
        if (bLabels[b].equals("=")) {
            // "=" spans 2 rows
            gbc.gridheight = 2;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        }
        else if (bLabels[b].equals("0")) {
            // "0" spans two cols
            gbc.gridy = 6;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = 2;
            gbc.gridheight = 1;
        }
        else if (bLabels[b].equals("3")) {
            gbc.gridheight = 1;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        }
        else if ((b + 1) % cols == 0) {
            gbc.gridheight = 1; 
            //end a row
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        }
        else {
            // for the "." button to be next to the "0"
            gbc.gridx = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
            gbc.gridheight = 1;
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        }

        //set the constraints and add it to the panel
        buttons[b].setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14));
        gbl.setConstraints(buttons[b], gbc);
        buttons[b].addActionListener(actionListener);
        buttons[b].addKeyListener(keyListener);
        add(buttons[b]);

        listeners = new Vector();
    }
}

private class ActionEventHandler implements ActionListener {
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        CalculatorKeypadEvent cke = new CalculatorKeypadEvent(event.getSource(), ((JButton)event.getSource()).getText());
        Iterator i = listeners.iterator();
        CalculatorKeypadListener ckl;
        while(i.hasNext()) {
            ckl = (CalculatorKeypadListener)i.next();
            ckl.calculatorKeyPressed(cke);
        }
    }
}

private class KeyEventListener extends KeyAdapter {
    
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        String key = CalculatorKeyMap.map(event);
        if (key != CalculatorKeyMap.UNKNOWN) {
            CalculatorKeypadEvent cke = new CalculatorKeypadEvent(event.getSource(), key);
            Iterator i = listeners.iterator();
            CalculatorKeypadListener ckl;
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                ckl = (CalculatorKeypadListener)i.next();
                ckl.calculatorKeyPressed(cke);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void addCalculatorKeypadListener(CalculatorKeypadListener ckl) {
    if (ckl == null) return;
    listeners.add(ckl);
}

public CalculatorKeypadListener[] getCalculatorKeypadListeners() {
    return (CalculatorKeypadListener[]) listeners.toArray();
}
}
```

At both instances of ckl.calculatorKeypadListener I get an error saying cannot find symbol. These are the only two errors I get and I’m sure it’s due to an update with Java. Can anyone help with what I'm doing wrong? I'm not looking to rewrite the entire thing if thats possible, just trying to figure out why it wont compile. Thanks!

Edit: Here is the whole program and below is the error message when compiling.

```
CalculatorKeypad.java:124: error: cannot find symbol
                                ckl.calculatorKeyPressed(cke);
                                   ^
  symbol:   method calculatorKeyPressed(CalculatorKeypadEvent)
  location: variable ckl of type CalculatorKeypadListener
```

Comment: So does your `CalculatorKeypadListener` have a method named `calculatorKeyPressed`? (Please don't use comments to clarify, [edit] your question instead. Code or errors are hard to read in comments.)

Comment: Edited the question. Thank you for showing me the ropes on how to ask. It also appears that I do not have a calculatorKeyPressed method.

Comment: Where are the classes `CalculatorKeypadListener` and `CalculatorKeypadEvent`? Please post them.

Comment: That is the full program besides what it is implementing. I guess it doesn't exist...

Comment: No, this can't be the full program. You have a class CalculatorKeypadListener defined somewhere which your compiler can see, but you haven't showed it to us. If that class didn't exist, the compiler would have given you an error message saying there's no such class.